# How do I bind the selected value of a kendoui dropdownlist to my model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, html.dropdownlistfor, cascadingdropdown

I have a KendoUI dropdownlist as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                  .Name("DeviceInterfaces")
                                  .OptionLabel("Select interface...")
                                  .DataTextField("Name")
                                  .DataValueField("Id")
                                  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetCascadeDeviceInterfaces", "EventTriggers")))
                            )
```

It's a cascading dropdownlist, how do I set whatever the user selects to the property of my model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's ok, I found out how to.

I have to use DropDownListFor instead of DropDownList, plus the .Name property has to match the Id of the model.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.EventTrigger.TriggerType)
.Name("EventTrigger.EventType")
```

Comment: If you are binding to the property using this line of code .DropDownListFor(m => m.EventTrigger.TriggerType) this make calling .Name() redundant

Comment: If you set the Name (as of 2015) it breaks the binding - at least it broke mine

Comment: I had to set Name to the exact spelling of the property i was binding to on the viewModel in-order to save the selected value on the form